# Ajax Window (Popup) Using Google Closure Library

Tags: javascript, user-interface, google-closure-library

Is there any class (like `goog.ui.dialog`) that let me show a dialog which its content can be fetched by **ajax** from another file?

- Is goog.ui.Dialog an appropriate class for this goal?
- Shall I implement it by other fundamental classes such as `good.net.XHR` and `goog.ui.Popup`?

Comment: "from another file" - you mean a script running outside your clojure application (and not a javascript in the application)?

Comment: no inside the application, but a server side file.

Answer (score 2):

You can extends the goog.ui.dialog and fetch the content.

A simple example wich can help you:

```
my.ui.Dialog = function(opt_iframe) {
  goog.ui.Dialog.call(this, null, opt_iframe);

  this.xhr_  = new goog.net.XhrIo();
  this.xhr_.addEventListener(goog.net.EventType.COMPLETE,
                             this.onComplete_, false, this);

  goog.events.listen(this, goog.ui.Dialog.EventType.SELECT,
                     this.dispatch_, false, this);
};
my.ui.Dialog.prototype.buildWindow_ = function (responseJson) {
  this.setTitle(responseJson.title);
  this.setContent(responseJson.content);
  this.setButtonSet(eval(responseJson.buttons));
};
my.ui.Dialog.EventType = {
  'COMPLETE': 'complete'
};
my.ui.Dialog.prototype.onComplete_ = function (event) {
var json = this.xhr_.getResponseJson ()
    this.buildWindow_ (json);
    this.reposition ();
};
my.ui.Dialog.prototype.send = function (uri, method, post_data) {
  this.xhr_.send(uri, method, post_data, null, {'X-DIALOG':'AJAX'});
};
goog.inherits (my.ui.Dialog, goog.ui.Dialog);
```

That's use a response in json to build the ui.Dialog like this:

```
{"buttons": "goog.ui.Dialog.Buttons.OK_CANCEL", 
 "content": "<html><body><h1>Hello</h1></body></html>", 
 "title": "Hello World"}
```

*This example can don't work directly :/*